# I am facing problem when I want to select the current row of gridview

Tags: c#

I need to select the row I am on and double click and explore. so my current challenge is to select the current row. It is not working as I wish. What could be the reason?

my code

```
Build(sqlConnection);

            aGv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            aGv.ReadOnly = true;
            aGv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
            aGv.MultiSelect = false;

            ReloadGrid();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `SelectionMode` to `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`.

Then you can get the double click event of your DataGridView this way :

```
this.aGv.CellContentDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.aGv_CellDoubleClick);
    
private void aGv_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        var selectedRow = aGv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    }
}
```